# Showing tags (keys and values) when converting .osm to .shp?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, openstreetmap, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-editor-osm

I would like to use OSM data as shapefile so that I could do some computations. So far, I have successfully loaded the OSM file in ArcMap 10.3.1 using the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap. The attribute table only shows the primary physical features such as highway, building, natural, etc.

How do I show the other tags, like building:level, building:material, etc., in the attribute table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation of [OpenStreetMap Toolbox](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=75716d933f1c40a784243198e0dc11a1), there is a detailed description on how to [extract specific tags](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor/wiki/Extracting-specific-tags), and it mentioned that:

> When you download data from OSM using the ArcGIS Editor for OSM tools,
>   you may find that certain information captured in the OSM tags is not
>   downloaded with the features. This is because only information that is
>   used for categorizing and symbolizing the data is downloaded
>   automatically; if all the tag information was downloaded, the result
>   would be an unwieldy attribute table with hundreds of columns, with
>   most of the values being 'Null'.
>
> If in your workflows you are always interested in a specific tag
>   value, you should update the 'Download, Extract, and Symbolize OSM
>   Data' model to include that tag.

Therefore, specific tags should be specified before start downloading of OSM data.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is unfortunately wrong. It is not true that you need to "specify tags before start downloading of OSM data." in order to be able to access other keys.

If there are missing attributes/keys, you can use the **"OSM Attribute Selector"**, tool to add them to your Feature Class table. This tool is also part of the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap toolbox.

OSM XML files downloaded and converted using the toolbox contain a special binary field used as a key/value storage similar to PostGreSQL HSTORE. This field contains full tagging info for a specific feature.

By using the **OSM Attribute Selector**, you can add the missing keys/attributes to your existing Feature Class table, as that tool will extract the required information from the key/value storage and create a physical field for it.

Comment: I think there is no reason to down vote my answer because it is correct. The information I provided comes from the developer of the tool as he mentioned it clearly and I quoted what he mentioned in documentation.

Comment: ahmadhanb. I appreciate you taking the effort to look up the documentation, but I have used this toolbox myself intensively in the past 4 years. And your answer is unfortunately wrong. The documentation is incomplete here. If you read carefully your own quote, you would notice it doesn't actually mention explicitely you can't access all other keys, just that the default set of keys is only a subset of all keys to prevent "an unwieldy table with hundreds of columns", and that one of the ways to include other keys is modifying the model. ESRI forgot to mention the OSM Attribute Selector though..